# Tabela editável com Jquery e PHP problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Boa tarde,
Estou com um problema, a uns dias tentando e não consigo resolver,
estou tentando fazer um tabela editável, o problema é que depois que eu pópulo a tabela com json não consigo fazer nada com as `<td>`, tudo que eu coloco via "`append`" não é reconhecido depois.

```
$("button[name='visualizar']").on('click', function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#tabela").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "php/select_db.php",
        success: function(dados) {
            for (i = 0; dados.length > i; i++) {
                $("#tabela").append("<tr><td>" + dados[i].modulo + "</td><td>" + dados[i].codigo + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fail");
        }
        //$("#aviso2").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

até aqui tudo beleza//

o código acima insere os dados na tabela, mas essas células que são inseridas via jquery não são reconhecidas posteriormente.

se eu usar `$("#tabela tbody tr td").dblclick(function()}`; nada acontece.

agora se eu criar uma tabela teste diretamente no front a função reconhece a tabela e executa o código que estiver dentro da função.
se alguém puder me ajudar, já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei o que causa este problema.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: no inicio do documento javascript você está usando o `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, acredito que seu problema esteja no escopo da árvore de DOM.

Quando você carrega um site, é gerado uma árvore de DOM e a inserção de fragmentos HTML posteriores não estarão nessa árvore e assim não serão reconhecidos.

Tenta isso depois:

```
 $('body').on('click','td',function(){
              //sua função
           });
```

A documentação: http://api.jquery.com/on/ ; pelo que entendo, o **on()** está acima da leitura do clique padrão e funciona desde que o elemento exista

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado amigo. funcionou :D